# Ruby shorthand for "use this if it isn't blank, otherwise use that"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
url = file.s3_url.blank? ? file.url : file.s3_url
```

Is there a shorter way to write this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, you could write a method on whatever `file` is an instance of (say `S3File`):

```
class S3File 
   def real_url
     self.s3_url.blank? ? self.url : self.s3_url
   end
   #...
end
```

Then it gets real simple:

```
url = file.real_url
```

As @tokland said, you *could* monkey patch `Object` to use an `or_if` method, which would be implemented like this:

```
class Object
   def or_if(method, val = nil)
      self.send(method) ? (block_given? ? yield : val) : self
   end         
end
```

This way, you'd be able to do this:

```
url = file.s3_url.or_if(:blank?) { file.url }
```

Or this:

```
url = file.s3_url.or_if(:blank?, file.url)
```

Comment: It'd be nice to have a standard `.or_if_blank?(...)` method analagous to the `IFNULL(...)` method in SQL.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't do it, but when you start down that road, you can end up with an app that's so full of sneaky methods it can be confusing for others to maintain. Having it a standard feature is always better. Fortunately a lot of my "hacks" end up, coincidentally, being taken up by ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 20):

There is an abstraction for that in ActiveSupport, [Object#presence](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#presence):

```
url = file.s3_url.presence || file.url
```

Comment: @tokland So this would be monkey-patched onto `String` I assume?

Comment: @Jacob. No, since this is generic, it would monkey-patch `Object`. If you want something only for `String#blank`, then yes, open just `String` and add the method "or_if_blank?"

Comment: @tokland Mind if I implement that in my answer?

Comment: @tokland Cool, check it out! :)

Comment: @tokland Nice answer by the way. :)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe, you can do the following:

```
url = file.s3_url || file.url
```

This code will only use file.url if file.s3_url is nil. That means that an empty string won't work though. If you want to ensure that an empty string is not used, like you do in your example, then there isn't a shorter way to do this.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but I'm not sure about the empty-string bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I use a utility method.

```
def until_not_blank(*args)
  args.find {|a| !a.blank? }
end

url = until_not_blank(file.s3_url, file.url)
```

I typically just put that in my ApplicationController and make it a helper. If you wanted it to be available globally, you could put it in Kernel, or you could monkey-patch Array

```
class Array
  def first_not_blank
    find {|a| !a.blank?}
  end
end

url = [file.s3_url, file.url].first_not_blank
```

Comment: This is also a good solution (the second approach feels more natural for Ruby). Just as a side note (as you surely know), the difference with || is  that it does not "short-circuit" the expression. But that's inevitable in a eager-evaluated language. You can always defer all the elements in the array with lambda/proc, but it would get so ugly I won't even write it :-)

Answer (score 0):

`url = (file.s3_url.blank?  && file.s3_url) || file.url`
Looks cool but I actually find it confusing and prefer good old ternary if.