# Ruby "return unless nil" idiom

Tags: ruby, idioms

I've got a smelly method like:

```
def search_record(*args)    
  record = expensive_operation_1(foo)
  return record unless record.nil?

  record = expensive_operation_2(foo, bar)
  return record unless record.nil?

  record = expensive_operation_3(baz)
  return record unless record.nil?

  record = expensive_operation_4(foo, baz)
  return record unless record.nil?
end
```

Is there a good ruby idiom for "return result of call unless nil"?

Or should I just write a `return_unless_nil(&blk)` method?

(Note that args are different for each call, so I can't simply just iterate over them)

Comment: Can record be `false`, or is definitely either a real record or nil?

Comment: "Or should I just write a `return_unless_nil(&blk)` method?" Which would return from the method that invoked it? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I have about 10 minutes of learning ruby under my belt, but am curious how would you write a method to possibly return a value for the caller?  As for a potential answer, I feel uncomfortable putting this as an actual answer given my very limited ruby exposure... can you have something like this in ruby?  `return (record=expensive_op(foo)) unless record.nil?`  Not sure if that's any less smelly for you either..

Comment: @at: Unfortunately that would not work, because in that type of expression Ruby will evaluate the right-hand side (the part after `unless`) before the left-hand side, so the assignment won't happen before you call `.nil?`. You could, however, do `(record = expensive_op(foo)) && (return record)`, but that's more parentheses than I prefer in my Ruby.

Comment: @Jordan: you're right and I assumed that's how ruby evaluated actually, I meant to write `return record unless (record=expens_op(foo)).nil?`.  Still, maybe not the most elegant code..

Comment: @Joshua-Cheek Yes, as far as I understand calling return from a block, returns from the function that yielded to the block.

Comment: Although I prefer the Jordan answer, I'd use `return record if record` instead of `return record unless record.nil?`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do you care about the difference between `nil` and `false` here? If you only care whether the return value of each method is "falsy," then this is a pretty Rubyish way of doing it:

```
def search_record(*args)    
  expensive_operation_1(foo)      ||
  expensive_operation_2(foo, bar) ||
  expensive_operation_3(baz)      ||
  expensive_operation_4(foo, baz)
end
```

If you're unfamiliar with this idiom, it can be explained thusly: Ruby, like most languages, ["short circuits"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) OR comparisons, meaning that if the first operand evaluates to "truey" it won't bother to evaluate the second operand (i.e. if `expensive_operation_1` returns something other than `nil` or `false`, it won't ever call `expensive_operation_2`), because it already knows that the result of the boolean operation is true.

Another useful thing that Ruby does is, instead of returning `true` or `false` from boolean operations it just returns the last operand it evaluates. So in this case if `expensive_operation_1` returns `nil`, it will then call `expensive_operation_2`, and if that returns a value (that isn't falsy), the whole expression will just evaluate to that value.

Finally, we can chain these booleans so, in effect, it will return the result of the first operand that isn't falsy and never evaluate the subsequent operands. If *all* of the operands evaluate to falsy, it will return the final operand (which we know is falsy and, in your case, probably `nil`).

Comment: To expand on Jordan's rather terse answer: The boolean operators short-circuit (evaluate only the left side if the right side isn't needed) and return the value that satisfied the operator.

Comment: Thanks Chuck. I was busy expanding on my answer when you commented. :)

Comment: The caveat "Do you care about the difference between nil and false" is indeed important. If any of these functions return a boolean, this code won't do. Unfortunately the OP has gone AWOL.

Comment: Sorry about going AWOL. You're right @Jordan; in this specific case I don't necessarily care about false vs nil, so I can just use standard short circuiting. I'm not quite sure why I fixated on making sure it's nil and missing the obvious path... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Complementing Jordan's answer: let's imagine these functions could return a boolean (unlikely for a search function, but anyway) and `||` does not work. We could then use the abstraction discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994354/ruby-shorthand-for-use-this-if-it-isnt-blank-otherwise-use-that):

```
expensive_operation_1(foo).or_if(:nil?) do
  expensive_operation_2(foo).or_if(:nil?) do
    expensive_operation_3(foo).or_if(:nil?) do
      expensive_operation_4(foo)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Object#or_if is an interesting idiom to keep in mind. Thanks!